# How to find a regular expression pattern without include it in the result?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, jar

I have a question about Java regular expression. How to find a regular expression pattern without include it in the result?

For example if the string is "1ab 2cd 3se 4ab" and I want to get the number that is followed by ab without including ab in the result.
The final result is "1 4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms, in particular positive look-ahead which is zero-width (it doesn't consume matched part, nor includes it in result).

In your case regex can look like `\\d(?=ab)` which means:

- `\\d` find single digit
- `(?=ab)` which is followed by `ab`

If your input can contain `1abc` which you don't want to accept you can add [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` after `ab` like `\\d(?=ab\\b)`.

Comment: sir, thanks for your feedback. up-votes. if the problem is more complex your way is more effectively. I'd like to use a `Matcher` too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like groups for example `(\\d+)ab`

```
String str = "1ab 2cd 3se 4ab";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)" + "ab");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
while (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println(mat.group(1));
    //----------------------^^------get the group(1) which mean get just the digit part
}
```

**Output**

```
1
4
```

---

1. `(\\d+)`  group of one or more digit
2. `ab`      followed by ab

Here is [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qpAFhr/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
                     // v--- replace "ab" with ""
String it=s.replaceAll("ab|\\s*\\dab\\w+|\\s*\\d(?:[^a]|\\w[^b])\\w*", "").trim(); 
//                                 |                |       |
//              replace "{digit}ab*" with ""        |       |
//                                                  |       |
//                                                  |       |
//                       replace " {digit}[not a]*" with "" |
//                                                          |                  
//                                                          |
//                                          replace " {digit}?[not b]*" with ""
```

### Output

```
"1ab 2cd 3se 4ab" -> "1 4"
"1ab 2cd 3se 5ac 4ab" -> "1 4"
"1ab 2cd 3se 4ab 6se" -> "1 4"
"1ab 2cd 3se 4ab 1qwer" -> "1 4"
"1qwer 2cd 3se 4ab 6se" -> "4"
"2cd 3se 4ab 6se 1qwer" -> "4"
"1abcd 2cd 3se 4ab" -> "4"
```

Comment: Will fail for `5ac`.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for your feedback. but I think I solved the OP's problem.

Comment: Will also fail for any non `ab` at the end the string i.e `6se` etc since they aren't followed by space

Comment: @degant yeah, but OP did not say it more. I'll fix my answer meet your needs.

Comment: @degant thanks for your feedback. how about it now?

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for your feedback. how about it now?

Comment: Better, but this still assumes that OP actually have input in form: one digit, to letters. Lets just hope that example is very precise and something like `1qwer` will never appear.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, sir. but his problem is so simpler, according to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle so I uses `replaceAll` rather than a `Matcher` .

Comment: @Pshemo sir, for `1qwer` you can add `\\w*` at the end of the regex to fix bug as further.

Comment: @Pshemo sir, How about it now?

Comment: It is working so I removed my down-vote, but I am not so sure about KISS here. You are just moving not too big confusion from `while(matcher.find()){matcher.group()}` structure into regex, which is IMO more complex now and will be harder to maintain (lets say that OP now wants to search for `[digit]abcdefg` - you are going to create spaghetti here). But let OP decide if this is what (s)he wants.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, sir. if the complex grows further I prefer to use a `Matcher` too.